# Can the mini-crossbow oneshot with tranquilizer darts?

Tags: deus-ex

I know that with a baton or a charge prod I can knock out a fellow from behind, but I never did good use of a crossbow without revealing myself post-shot.

Do I have to master the pistol skill? is there another way maybe?

Comment: Yeah, a headshot will take them out almost instantly. Otherwise you alert and you have to watch them twitch for about a minute while they attack you until they pass out (maybe).

Comment: In addition to the twitch, there should be a sound cue of them shouting in pain, which means the health is slowly depleting. And AFAIK, body shot never oneshots them.

Comment: @antimo yeah but even if I aimed for the head, they twitch instead of passing out. As Dulkan says, which seems logical to me, the helmets they wear would prevent one-shooting with tranq. darts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @GeoffAtkins said, a headshot will incapacitate the enemy immediately (or at least very quickly) and unless there is somebody around to witness the person falling down no alert will be raised. To reliably land headshots a good pistol skill level is very useful. Also useful: The accuracy mod for the crossbow as well as laser and/or scope.

A word of caution though: Later in the game several enemies will wear helmets which render them immune to headshots with tranq darts.

Comment: Oh crap, I exactly wanted to take them down in one shot with tranq darts using the head. Oh well, guess I have to go on their backs one by one with the baton. lol